# BAT: if statement based on modify date of file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, last-modified

I want to see if a lock file modify date is more than a 5 seconds ago or it in the future (indicating the PC clock was changed back).

How can I say

- if file.modifydate < now - 5 seconds or modifydate > now

  - run command a (command a will launch my Java app)
- else

  - run command b (command b will send a UDP packet to a localhost port)

Comment: does it need to be a batch file, or is vbscript acceptable too?

Comment: That is an interesting idea. I think vbscript will work fine. Can we launch vbscript without showing any terminal windows?

Comment: when you use wscript.exe to start the script, you don't see anything unless you output anything in the script.

Comment: It's hard to get the seconds part of a file with pure batch, you normaly get only something like `16.06.2011 07:44` with `dir` or `FOR %a in (myfile) do echo %~ta`

Comment: I will be using either VBScript or JavaScript. @Wimmel, please make an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @George, I think it is better if you describe in an answer how you have solved your problem, and accept that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wimmel suggested, I will be using VBScript - well actually I will be using JScript in the same way VBScript would normally be used... because I am already familiar with JavaScript.

I posted this question: [Windows XP and Up: JavaScript instead of VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348845/windows-xp-and-up-javascript-instead-of-vbscript)

Which has the code I will be using

for checking modify date/time

```
var o = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = o.GetFile("c:\\temp\\test.js");
// WScript.Echo(file.DateLastModified); // This is the modify date/time with seconds
```

and code to exec my Java process

```
WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var result = WshShell.Run("command-goes-here", 0, true);
// WSH.Echo(result); // this is the exit code
```

command b will be to send the UDP packet using one of the suggestions from [Windows BAT or CMD: send some data to a localhost udp port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336941/windows-bat-or-cmd-send-some-data-to-a-localhost-udp-port).

The commands would probably be the same if I used VBScript/JScript so they should work fine.

The only thing missing is: [VBScript/JScript Networking: Connect either UDP or TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348907/vbscript-jscript-networking-connect-either-udp-or-tcp)

If I could use a native function, it would definitely be better than an exec of command b.